# Jquery Wordpress Visual composer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I wrote the javascript, which is working absolutely fine on my computer. It shows popup window with some text and image when you press on iv element. But with wordpress it does not work. On wordpress it adds the image, which should be in popup window, bellow the content of the website.

In developer tool it shows the error:
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$j('[data-q_id="'+a+'"]').offset().top')

Here is the code

```
    <body>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
           $(function() {

$('#clickMe1').click(function(event) {
    var mytext = $('#literOne').val();


    $('<div id="dialog">'+mytext+'</div>').appendTo('body');        
    event.preventDefault();

        $("#dialog").dialog({                   
            width: 600,
            modal: true,
            close: function(event, ui) {
                $("#dialog").remove();
                }
            });
    }); //close click
});
</script>    
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {

$('#clickMe2').click(function(event) {
    var mytext = $('#literTwo').val();


    $('<div id="dialog">'+mytext+'</div>').appendTo('body');        
    event.preventDefault();

        $("#dialog").dialog({                   
            width: 600,
            modal: true,
            close: function(event, ui) {
                $("#dialog").remove();
                }
            });
    }); //close click
});

  </script>

    <style>
    .pi_liter{
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    </style>
    <!-- begin planirovki  -->
    <div class="planirovki">
        <div class="plan_img_main">
            <div class="plan_img" id="plans">
                <div class="wmain" id="ankor1">
                    <div class="pi_liter pl1" section="1" id="clickMe1">
                        Литер 1

<textarea cols="0" rows="0" id="literOne" style="display:none">Some hidden text display none <img src="http://cu33132.tmweb.ru/domnasobornoy/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/400.jpg"  />
</textarea>

                    </div>



                    <div class="pi_liter pl2" section="2" id="clickMe2">
                        Литер 2

<textarea cols="0" rows="0" id="literTwo" style="display:none">Some hidden text display none two <img src="http://cu33132.tmweb.ru/domnasobornoy/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/400.jpg" />
</textarea>


                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end planirovki -->

</div>
<!-- end container_main -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_adapt.css">



</body>
```

CSS

```
.wmain{max-width:1180px;margin:0 auto;}

.planirovki{}
.planirovki .tm{padding-top:88px;}
.planirovki .tm span{padding-bottom:0;padding-top:15px;}
.plan_head{padding-bottom:67px;}
.plan_img{background:url(http://cu33132.tmweb.ru/domnasobornoy/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/400.jpg) no-repeat center top;}
.plan_img .wmain{height:1144px;position:relative;}
.pi_liter{text-align:center;font-size:24px;color:#003d7f;text-transform:uppercase;font-family:'Kudrashov Plain:001.001', arial;width:171px;height:125px;background:url(http://cu33132.tmweb.ru/domnasobornoy/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/plan_plashka.png) no-repeat;line-height:42px;position:absolute;cursor:default;padding-top:44px;}
.pi_liter span{font-size:17px;}
.pl1{left:73px;top:11px;}
.pl2{left:821px;top:11px;}
.pi_liter{-webkit-transition:0.3s;-moz-transition:0.3s;-ms-transition:0.3s;-o-transition:0.3s;transition:0.3s;}
.pi_liter:hover{-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);-moz-transform:scale(1.1);-ms-transform:scale(1.1);-o-transform:scale(1.1);transform:scale(1.1);}
```

related url is http://cu33132.tmweb.ru/domnasobornoy/#plan

Thank you in advance! 
Hope you can help me

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? What is it doing vs. what do you expect it to do? Have you checked your developer tools (hit F12 on Windows, Opt+Cmd+I on Mac) for errors?

Comment: @MikeC I edited the post. Thanks !